# Remeasure NestedScrollView height after adding a new view

Tags: android, kotlin, scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

I have a `NestedScrollView` that inside of it contains multiple `CardViews`. The last card in the list has a button that when tapped adds a `LinearLayout` at the bottom of the card which contains a list of things. At the same time when tapping on that button I also want the card to be scrolled to the top of the screen. The problem is the nestedScrollView does not know that a new view was added at the bottom of the card and it doesn't scroll at all.

```
fun onButtonClicked() {
    binding.cardView.addView(linearLayout)  
    binding.nestedScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, cardView.top)
}
```

The `smoothScrollTo` doesn't do anything since the card is still considered to be the last one in the list with nothing under it even though I attached to it a new view.
I've tried multiple things, including invalidate(), requestLayout(), forceLayout() on the scrollView and on the card as well but nothing seems to work.

Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: In case you still need help, did you try "binding.nestedScrollView.requestLayout()" ?